# how can i remove incorrect results from memory?

Tags: python-3.x, comparison, product, python-itertools

```
import itertools
printable = 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxz'
all_possibilites = ([''.join(i) for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 3)])
comparison = ['zd']
if comparison in all_possibilities:
    print("match")
```

This is a snippet of my code. my intention is to generate every single combination of the alphabet. The snippet here has a limit of three characters. With the limit too large python returns memory error. My question is:

Is there a way to remove from memory the combinations that did not match in order for the only limitation to be time, instead of memory? say if the character limit was 5? Any further reading on this would be helpful too.

Comment: What exactly is the purpose you're trying to achieve? What do you mean by all possible combination of the alphabet?  There will be infinite combinations as you increase the repeat size towards infinity.  Any n-letter combination that you make will exist, so what is the purpose of a comparison?  If I have itertools.product(range(3),repeat = 3) you will have every possible 3-digit combination of 0,1, and 2 - you don't need to check whether it exists or not.  Of course the memory will fill up fast.. with n =  5 you have 26^5 combinations already.

Answer (score 0):

The main fault is that you're first creating the full list and then trying to filter it out. That's an issue because you bring the full list in memory.

You'd be better adding your condition inside the list-comprehension, keeping any elements you'll actually need:

```
all_posibilities = ["".join(i) for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 5) if 'a' or 'b' in i]
                                      ## ^^ place your condition here
print(len(all_posibilities))
```

Alternatively, if you're looking to iterate through `all_posibilities` in the end, it makes sense to create a generator to further limit the memory footprint:

```
all_posibilities = ("".join(i) for i in itertools.product(printable, repeat = 5) if 'a' or 'b' in i)
for i in all_posibilities: 
    # do things
```